# Update file in Google Drive with "resumable" uploadType via Google Drive API

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

Now i'm working with GoogleDrive API for iOS ( i don't use the Objective-C client library ) and I can update file's data only by "media" uploadType, file's data and/or file's meta-data by "multipart" uploadType, but I can't update anything with "resumable" uploadType.

By google's API references, request update file uses method PUT, but request with "resumable" uploadType uses method POST in the first request to send meta-data of file only, the second request with PUT method send data of file, this make me confused so much. Anyone has any suggestion for me T_T ?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I did it:

Request 1:

Header:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Type: video/mp4
X-Upload-Content-Length: 7421411
```

Body:

```
{
   Meta-data of files to upload
}
```

After received upload_id from Location header of response 1, call the 2nd request:

Header:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=adZc...
Content-Length: 7421411
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

Body:

```
{
   bytes of file to upload
}
```

Comment: Where do you specify the fileID which you are updating?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using XMLHTTP request or using the Google Drive SDK API.  request = gapi.client.request(); and request.exeute().

Most important question is are you able to send the next chunk.  What is the point of doing an resumable upload with the full set of bytes.  The point for resumable upload is to use chunking.
Upload is resumable from the next chunk, i.e technically on the next chunk, the filesize should increase.  I don't mind if the server doesn't give me number of bytes received.  I need to know if the file is increasing.  If the file size is increasing, I can simply offset the bytes to upload to the diff of filesize and the data I send.

If by definition of what you are doing, resumable upload is supported by default.  All you have to do is use:
'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files/'+ NewFileID,

the NewFileID can by any file ID old or new.  It will still update the file with new bytes.

So, I am not sure what is the advantage of you are doing?  Did you figure out how to send the next chunk (256KB default) and confirm that the filesize on the google drive change to a value:
First ChunkSize +  + New ChunkSize +

First ChunkSize : your initial chunk that you put. Example 256KB
  : This is space allocated by Google drive for storing its metadata.
New ChunkSize: You second Chunck size (which should be default 256KB again)
: This is again metadata stored by Google drive for storing the next chunk.
So total size by the time both are processed should be > 512KB